# What's the appropriate format to ensure that the html content in textedit can be opened in the browser?

Tags: html

I was writing a really basic webpage in textEdit(the built in app in Mac). My code looks like this but when I opened it with Chrome, it looks the same instead of showing the real title and paragraph. I'm grateful if someone can help me out!

[image: Here's the original code]

[image: Here's how it looks in Chrome]

Comment: what did you save the file as?

Comment: Untitled1.html  I'm not sure if it's the problem with the code...

Answer (score 0):

Save the file with .html extension and it will be opened in browser. Save something like FileName.html

Comment: I saved it as Untitled1.html but I'm not sure if it's the problem with the code, like I need some header or stuff... Thanks!

Comment: There is no problem with your code. May be it might be saved as Untitled1.html.txt Once check that.